# psql still exists despite uninstalling

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu, linux-mint, apt

I installed psql on my system without having added any new package sources. Later,I added postgres's package repo following [the instructions on their website](https://www.postgresql.org/download/linux/ubuntu/) and ran `sudo apt install postgres`. I then ran `sudo apt remove postgres`.

Now, when I run `sudo apt remove postgresql` again, `apt` tells me "Unable to locate package postgresql". However, running `dpkg -l | grep sql` yields (among other things):

```
ii  postgresql-14                              14.5-0ubuntu0.22.04.1                      amd64        The World's Most Advanced Open Source Relational Database
ii  postgresql-15                              15.1-1.pgdg22.04+1                         amd64        The World's Most Advanced Open Source Relational Database
ii  postgresql-client-14                       14.5-0ubuntu0.22.04.1                      amd64        front-end programs for PostgreSQL 14
ii  postgresql-client-15                       15.1-1.pgdg22.04+1                         amd64        front-end programs for PostgreSQL 15
ii  postgresql-client-common                   246.pgdg22.04+1                            all          manager for multiple PostgreSQL client versions
ii  postgresql-common                          246.pgdg22.04+1                            all          PostgreSQL database-cluster manager
```

And running `psql --version` from the command line yields `psql (PostgreSQL) 15.1 (Ubuntu 15.1-1.pgdg22.04+1)`.

Here are some questions, info about any is appreciated:

- Why can't apt find the `postgresql` package even though `psql` is installed?

  - What package is `psql` part of and how do I figure that out? Does `psql` still exist on my system because it is part of a package that another package I have installed depends on?
- I'm just interested in using the most recent LTS version of postgres (15.1 at the time I'm writing this). Do I need the version 14 packages which exist on my systems? If not, how do I remove them?

Edit: After `sudo apt remove`ing `postgresql-14` and `postgresql-15`, psql still exists on my system but gives the following error: `psql: error: connection to server on socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432" failed: No such file or directory`. Why does the psql command still work?

Comment: Because there is no `postgres` package, there is a `postgresql` package.  Also there are multiple `postgresql`  packages  installed. If you want to remove(make sure you have backup of any data) just the 14 version then `sudo apt remove postgresql-14`. FYI,  there is no LTS version of Postgres, they all have 5 years of community support.

Comment: Thank you. I replaced the faulty package name in the relevant commands. It seems that what's happening in my original post remains though. I `sudo apt remove`ed `postgresql`, `postgresql-14`, and `postgresql-15` yet my dpkg output remains the same. Running psql now gives an error though (updated in original question). Do you know why this is?

Comment: 1) On command line run `pg_lsclusters`. 2) Do you really want to get rid of all the Postgresql packages?  If so you will need to do `sudo apt purge postgresql-14`. **Note** this can clean out everything. Pay attention to what the pop dialog is asking. 3) `psql` is the Postgres client. To get rid of it do `sudo apt remove  postgresql-client-14` and for whatever other versions. It does not harm anything to keep it around though.

Comment: 1) My terminal was not able to find that command, I've just been playing around with postgres on this machine, I stored nothing of value. 2 and 3) I purged postgresql-{client-,}{14,15,} then ran `sudo apt autoremove`. My terminal can no longer find psql but dpkg shows that I still have postgresql-client-common and postgresql-client, how do I figure out what packages these belong to? I'm trying to remove bloat from my machine, hence this purging :)

Comment: You will need to do `sudo apt purge ...` for each package you want to get rid of. Then `sudo apt autoremove`. Probably a good idea to search for a tutorial on how to use `apt`. This [Ubuntu Apt](https://ubuntu.com/server/docs/package-management) is a good starting point.